# Inno setup Uninstall progress bar

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup script I uninstall a 3rd party program via `[UninstallRun]`. But I have to run another .exe to check when this has finished. While I'm running this other .exe the uninstall form looks like its a 1% and isn't doing anything. How do i effect the progress bar of the uninstall form?

I've looked at using `UninstallProgressForm` but I'm not sure where to run this?

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{{69E3F70C-32B2-47A8-A70D-653D16ECEFC2}\setup.exe"; Parameters:  "-psc_s -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly"
Filename: "{app}\WaitForUninstall.exe"
```

Comment: You don't need to wait for the app. to complete with another application. There's the [`waituntilterminated`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=waituntilterminated) which should do that for you. About the progress bar; what exactly do you want to achieve ? Can you get a progress from that installer that you execute ? Or how do you want to present that something is happening to the user ?

Comment: Hi TLama I have to wait with another app because the first one doesn't send a stop command so Inno setup thinks its complete. With the progress bar I'd like it to be set to say 90 or 100 and have a busy cursor so it at least looks like it doing something